# Test for a certain character in a text file

Tags: cmd

I have a system generated text file (20 characters). If the contents begin with the # character I want to create another text file with "No text available" as the only contents.
If the first character is not a #, the new text file should contain precisely the same text as the source file.

I need to achieve this on a windows xp machine without installing any additional software.

I could do it easily in Python, but I guess this would have to be a windows cmd job.

Any help gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the file always contains exactly one line of txt:

```
>outputFile.txt (findstr /v "^#" inputFile.txt || echo No text available)
```

If the file can contain multiple lines

```
>outputFile.txt (findstr /n "^#" inputFile.txt | >nul findstr /b "1:" && (echo No text available) || type inputFile.txt)
```

Comment: This needs to run every few seconds, is there a way to loop it? Thanks.

Comment: Daft question, sorted it. Very tired 6am!